# my right image changes slides but the left one is stuck on the first slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have created two changing image galleries side by side but my right image changes slides but the left one is stuck on the first slide. does anyone know why? I have found the code on W3.CSS but I changed the class "changing-photo-right" and "changing-photo-left" to one of my own class (which can be found in my css stylesheet) and did not link the style sheet of W3.css.

```css
.section2 {
  background: #F5DAD3;
  display: flex;
  height: 750px; 
  position: relative;
}


.changing-photo-left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 125px;
  margin-top: -390px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.changing-photo-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 125px;
  margin-top: -390px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}



.section3 {
  height: 440px;
  width: 2px; 
  top: 160px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hmm">
            <div class="section2"></div>
            <div class="section3" ></div>
            <div>
                <p class="text-12">The interieur</p>
                <p class="text-11">Discover the lovely interieur that was built since 1948.</p>
                <a class="button-intro-below-left" href="">Click here for more</a>
                <div class="changing-photo-left" style="max-width:500px">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="009.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="062.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="027.jpg" style="width:100%">
                </div>
                  
                  <script>
                  var myIndex = 0;
                  carousel();
                  
                  function carousel() {
                    var i;
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                      x[i].style.display = "none";  
                    }
                    myIndex++;
                    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
                    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                    setTimeout(carousel, 2500); // Change image every 3 seconds
                  }
                  </script>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p class="text-13">The exterior</p>
                <p class="text-14">Discover the lovely exterior that was built since 1948.</p>
                <a class="button-intro-below-right" href="">Click here for more</a>
                <div class="changing-photo-right" style="max-width:500px">
                    <img class="mySlides1" src="009.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides1" src="012.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides1" src="013.jpg" style="width:100%">
                </div>

                <script>
                    var myIndex = 0;
                    carousel();
                    
                    function carousel() {
                      var i;
                      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
                      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        x[i].style.display = "none";  
                      }
                      myIndex++;
                      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
                      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                      setTimeout(carousel, 2500); // Change image every 3 seconds
                    }
                    </script>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same names for the `variables` and `functions` in both of the loops. If you change the names of the `variables` and `functions` in the second loop, everything should work just fine.

```css
.section2 {
    background: #F5DAD3;
    display: flex;
    height: 750px; 
    position: relative;
  }
  
  
  .changing-photo-left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-top: -390px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .changing-photo-right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 125px;
    margin-top: -390px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  
  
  
  .section3 {
    height: 440px;
    width: 2px; 
    top: 160px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="hmm">
        <div class="section2"></div>
        <div class="section3" ></div>
        <div>
            <p class="text-12">The interieur</p>
            <p class="text-11">Discover the lovely interieur that was built since 1948.</p>
            <a class="button-intro-below-left" href="">Click here for more</a>
            <div class="changing-photo-left" style="max-width:500px">
                <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1672426142068-c2103a852426?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" style="width:100%">
                <img class="mySlides" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1409254639/photo/autumn-drive.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=phQOICvfLifPWESZu3AioY7sKM9s_HQnCozMKF6g120=" style="width:100%">
                <img class="mySlides" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1427249962/photo/tropical-leaves-abstract-green-leaf-texture-in-garden-nature-background.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=40KcV7mbAQWihuO0At8GSOTIKp-TvIoHGIhurHBeUq0=" style="width:100%">
            </div>
              
              <script>
                var myIndex = 0;
                carousel();
                
                function carousel() {
                  var i;
                  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";  
                  }
                  myIndex++;
                  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
                  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                  setTimeout(carousel, 2500); // Change image every 3 seconds
                }
              </script>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p class="text-13">The exterior</p>
            <p class="text-14">Discover the lovely exterior that was built since 1948.</p>
            <a class="button-intro-below-right" href="">Click here for more</a>
            <div class="changing-photo-right" style="max-width:500px">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1672426142068-c2103a852426?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" style="width:100%">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1409254639/photo/autumn-drive.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=phQOICvfLifPWESZu3AioY7sKM9s_HQnCozMKF6g120=" style="width:100%">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1427249962/photo/tropical-leaves-abstract-green-leaf-texture-in-garden-nature-background.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=40KcV7mbAQWihuO0At8GSOTIKp-TvIoHGIhurHBeUq0=" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <script>
                var myIndex1 = 0;
                carousel1();
                
                function carousel1() {
                  var j;
                  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
                  for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
                    y[j].style.display = "none";  
                  }
                  myIndex1++;
                  if (myIndex1 > y.length) {myIndex1 = 1}    
                  y[myIndex1-1].style.display = "block";  
                  setTimeout(carousel1, 2500); // Change image every 3 seconds
                }
                </script>

        </div>
```